# Advice on optimizing process - JSON -> pandas -> csv and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, json, pandas

***Disclosure:*** I am not developer or something and just had to do it because, well, I had to do it. Of course, I was super proud when coded hangman in python but that was pretty it.

So I had to put data from one service to MySQL table, and connect to it through their aggregation API. To my surprise everything is working as expected BUT there are two problems:

1. Script is suuuuuper slow. It takes around 500-700 seconds to execute it.
2. It works when I run it manually, but it timeouts on scheduler.

So **my question** to you, fellow community, could you hint me what should I read or, maybe, change to make it at least a little bit faster.

As a business background, I have to run separate queries on 10 different languages, but in the code below, I provide only one language and put description around it.

The timeout on scheduled execution is somewhere between 5th and 6th language.

```py
# used modules
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import MySQLdb
url = 'here comes URI to service API aggregation call'
headers = {'Integration-Key':'Key','Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
# the next one is different request for each of 10 languages, so 10 variables.
data_language = '''{Here comes a long long JSON request so API can aggregate it all }'''
# requesting data from API
# Again, 10 times for the next block
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data_en)
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
df_en = pd.DataFrame(json_data['results'])
# So on schedule, it time outs after 5th or 6th language
# creating merged table
df = pd.concat([df_en,df_sv,and_so_on],ignore_index=True)
db=MySQLdb.connect(host="host", user="user",passwd="pws",db="db")
df.to_sql(con=db, name='nps', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never found `to_sql` to work for datasets that are at all large. I recommend turning your dataframe into a CSV and then using psycopg2 to do a bulk `COPY` up to your table.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to do it - hope it will speed it up. However, I still need to figure our how to make sure that script is executed until this line and not timed out...

Comment: Which line is causing the timeout?

Comment: So i have these three lines for each of 10 languages - couldn't figure out how to do it through loop, so yeah, 30 duplicated lines.And it actually causes error on json.loads() part, so I assume it might be a problem with requests.post()

Comment: response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data_en)
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
df_en = pd.DataFrame(json_data['results'])

Comment: Yeah, if you're having timeouts when using requests, consider asking a new question.